# React-navigation error when pushing new screen

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

**ISSUE:** issue is not coming in compile time , if its compile time then some thing wrong with syntax but its coming when I am pushing , and controls not reach to next screen means render and constructor .so issue at when I am pushing using navigation. some thing wrong to make push new screen but whats issue how to fix.

I am getting some error when trying to push new screen . same screen I am pushing from other screen its working fine , but I have added custom header in navigationOptions and setParams for custom action , all action working fine , now I am trying to go another screen from this screen getting issue not able to find what is issue ,

I am using     **"react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.11",**

**code I used for header , and set action working fine**

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: '',
    headerTintColor: variables.white,
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: variables.spoRed },
    gesturesEnabled: false,
    // custom header
    header: (
      <Header
        onChangeText={
          navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.onChangeText
        }
        goBack={navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.goBack}
        seachAction={
          navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.seachAction
        }
      />
    ),
  });
```

**here I setParams to fire action from header working fine**

```
componentWillMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({
          onChangeText: this.onChangeText,
          goBack: this.goBack,
          seachAction: this.seachAction,
        });
```

**//here is my code to push new screen but getting error**

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(
   'detail',
   {},
   NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'DETAILSA' }),
 );
```

whats issue not able to find , what I am doing wrong here

[image]

Comment: I believe that your components should start with a capital letter. <header> should be <Header>

Comment: thats is not an issue , I updated issue still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because the title is an empty string. Use `title: ' '`, or upgrade to latest version to solve the problem.

Comment: how its matter , because current screen not an issue and trying to push new screen then I got issue , in push call

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem here is with react-navigation.

You're rendering a string somewhere that is not wrapped with `Text`. Maybe, check the render method of the component you use in `detail` route.

Comment: I checked , issue not in component , I tried to push from other screen its woking , but not working from when adding custom header and setParams action

Comment: Not sure exactly where the problem lies. Can you share your component and customer header code?

Check your render methods and component names.